# Error converting data type varchar to float in assigned column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hey I am trying to convert the data type from varchar to float of the column name 'Identification'. Below are the queries that I have created and both are throwing the error

```
Select distinct Convert(float,(Replace([Identification], '-','')))  FROM [A]
where identification is NOT Null;


Select Cast(Replace([Identification], '-','') AS FLOAT) FROM [A]
where identification is NOT Null;
```

> Error Msg:
> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
> Error converting data type varchar to float.

Comment: The error is telling you the problem, what about the error don't you understand and we can try to elaborate. Also, SQL Server 2008 has been out of support for over a year now, and you should really be looking at upgrades. Because you're using an unsupported you don't even have access to `TRY_CAST`/`TRY_CONVERT`, which really hinders fixing your data.

Comment: I know what the problem is. But I am struggling hard to fix the issue. Can you tell me how can I change the datatype? Also I have used the Cast and Convert function but it's not working. Check my responses above

Comment: You have bad data in your column. This is just one reason why storing numerical data in `(n)varchar` is a bad idea, and you need to fix your design. Unfortunately, like I mentioned, as you're using unsupported software you can't use `TRY_CONVERT`; personally I would suggest you really look at those upgrades now.

Comment: I can't upgrade because I don't have access. That's a DBA job. I need to sort out the solution into my domain

Answer (score 0):

```
select cast('' as xml).value('xs:float(sql:column("val"))', 'float')
from (values ('a'),('b'), ('-123'))  v(val);



CREATE TABLE ATest(Identification varchar(100));

INSERT INTO ATest(Identification) 
VALUES('A'),('B'), ('A-B-123'), ('123-456'), ('1-1-1-1-1'), 
('123-E10'), /*you might need to handle this type of values when scientific notation should NOT be converted to float...
....eg. just replace E with another letter*/
('------1------')
;

SELECT
    Identification, ReplacedIdentification, 
    cast('' as xml).value('xs:float(sql:column("src.ReplacedIdentification"))', 'float') as ToFloatOrNull
FROM
(
Select [Identification], Replace([Identification], '-','') ReplacedIdentification
FROM [ATest]
WHERE[Identification] IS NOT Null
) as src
--use this to find Identification values which cannot be converted to float
--WHERE cast('' as xml).value('xs:float(sql:column("src.ReplacedIdentification"))', 'float') IS NULL;

DROP TABLE Atest;
GO
```

Comment: I didn't get this. Can you please explain properly?

Answer (score 0):

```
Haaaz, try this:

   CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC([Identification]) THEN CONVERT(float, 
    [Identification])
```

Comment: I am still getting same error below.
"Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
Error converting data type varchar to float.
"

Comment: Please, type your current query

Comment: Select Cast(Replace(Replace([Identification], '-',''),',','') AS FLOAT) FROM [A]
where identification is NOT Null;

Comment: Please, try new query